# Routes file lost - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Just started out working with Laravel and Homestead.

I followed below guide for that :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3kaQDFJiis

and did everything exactly the same, but when I open my project Laravel/app/Http there's no routes.php file just kernel.php.

What could possibly cause this? How to fix this? Maybe I messed up something during installation? I did try to re-install everything, but I faced same problem.

Comment: Which laravel version are you using?

Comment: The file has been changed in [5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing). The route is now `routes/web.php`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the latest version of Laravel, the routes can now be found in

```
Laravel/routes/
```

This folder contains 3 different files each used for their respective consumption methods `api` `web` `console`

Comment: I just check with laravel 5.3 `web.php` was under `projectname/routes/` directory not under `app`. what version you have checked?

Comment: Sorry small mistake. `Laravel/routes` is what i meant

Answer (score 1):

Keep note that from Laravel 5.3 the `routes.php` file has been removed and moved to

```
laravel_project_folder/routes/web.php
laravel_project_folder/routes/api.php
```

> See [Laravel 5.3 Routing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing) & [Laravel Upgrade Guide Section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I just check with laravel 5.3 `web.php` was under `projectname/routes/` directory not under `app`. can you please check once at your end?

Comment: @RaunakGupta - Yup, you're correct, I've updated my answer, thaks for pointing it out! :D

Comment: No problem, we all are here to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I think you are using laravel latest version which is "**5.3.***". 
>   From laravel 5.3 routes has found a new home which is under
>   **`projectname/routes/`**.

`routes` directory has 3 php file

1. api.php
2. console.php
3. web.php

*You can check your Laravel version form `projectname/composer.json` under `require` as "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"*

---

Reference:

- [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/releases#laravel-5.3)

Answer (score 0):

You will find it in 
1)routes/web.php
You can also read the use of api.php and console.php files as they are also used in routing